# What is a good architecture for user-facing highly parallelized work on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-dynamodb, cloud

I'd like to build a user facing application that has a computationally intensive backend which is highly parallelizable.

I'm using AWS.

In the past, I used Lambda to parallelize, and DynamoDB to store shared state amongst my lambdas.

However, I quickly run into the 40,000 writes-per-second throttling of DynamoDB.

Elasticache look like a promising replacing for DynamoDB, however it seems optimized for scaling reads, not writes.

DynamoDB Dax also looks promising.

This seems like a common scenario. Is there an established pattern for implementing it?

I came across AWS Batch, and ParallelCluster, but they don't seem intended for user-facing applications (more like a Data Scientist running some ad-hoc workloads).

Comment: That's some seriously high volume. 40k writes per second sustained for on-demand would cost $132k/mo.

Comment: It isn't going to be sustained at that capacity. Just when a user (very few internal) throws a new dataset at it, it'll parallelize and crunch the data quickly, and then go silent until the next user comes.

Comment: Probably this isn't as common a scenario as I imagined :)

Comment: The closest equivalent to dynamodb is cassandra, but AWS doesn't have a hosted offering for it

Comment: @jordanm https://aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/

Comment: Another idea that I encountered along the way. Use step functions for the state saving. You can use parallelism to run multiple steps in SF (each step is a lambda) and let the SF engine save the state for you. We've seen being done for ML model training. See https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html or https://lumigo.io/aws-serverless-ecosystem/aws-step-functions-limits-use-cases-best-practices/

Comment: Update: we were actually running into DynamoDB partition limits, not table limits. We were using DynamoDB to keep track of large sets. We were using the partition keys are the set id, and the sort key for items that belonged in the set. This led to hot partitions. I've switched to using S3 prefixes for each set, and objects in those prefixes for each item in the set. This new pattern works great. S3 also has a capacity-per-prefix model, but it is more forgiving that DynamoDB's partition limit.